# hide and show names using react hooks

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am new to react hooks,
- in my app initially, all the names of the users should be hidden.
- later when I click each user it should show the name.
- so I used the show and setshow.
- when I tried to print the values in the browser, I don't see it.`return(<div>{show}users Data{setShow}`
- I wrote click for each user but I am not sure how to hide and show.
- there will be millions of users in my app, so whats the best way to hide and show the name when I click each
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t1mdfj?file=index.js

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

function DataClick(){
  const [show, setShow]= useState(false);

  function showItem(e){
    console.log("e--->", e.target);
    setShow(true);
  }
  return(<div>{show}users Data{setShow}
  <div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user1</div>
    <div>John</div>
  <div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user2</div>
    <div>Mike</div>

    <div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user3</div>
    <div>Mike3</div><div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user4</div>
    <div>Mik4e</div><div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user5</div>
    <div>Mike5</div><div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user6</div>
    <div>Mike6</div><div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user7</div>
    <div>Mike7</div><div onClick= {showItem}
  //onClick={()=>setShow(true)}
    >user8</div>
    <div>Mike8</div>

  </div>);
}



render(<DataClick />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: use a forEach and loop through the number of users.

Comment: What do you expect this line to do: `return(<div>{show}users Data{setShow}`?

Comment: I thought in the browser it will shows as `false users Data true`. Since on the top we used this line `const [show, setShow]= useState(false);`

Comment: @Tick20 can you update in my stackblitz its so confusing :(

Comment: @computer cool, please check my answer posted. I have also updated in your stackblitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@computer cool, Please see the below implementation to show and hide the usernames when user id is clicked, this is an updated code of @JMadelaine's implementation. Hope this will help. (In @JMadelaine's implementation one drawback I found is, once the username is shown it was not hiding back when clicking on the user id again because he was always setting the state to *true* onClick), please see the below code.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

const UserItem = ({ user }) => {
  const [isNameShown, setIsNameShown] = useState(false)

  const handleChange = () => {
    setIsNameShown(prevState => !prevState)
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={handleChange} >
      <div>{user.id}</div>
      {isNameShown && <div>{user.name}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}

function DataClick() {
  const users = [
    {
      id: 'user1',
      name: 'John',
    },
    {
      id: 'user2',
      name: 'Peter',
    },
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map(user => <UserItem user={user} />)}
    </div>
  )
}


export default DataClick;
```

Here the handleChange function sets the value of the state using the previous value by passing a callback function instead of direct value, so this callback function will get the previous state as argument and returns the inverted value, so if the user is opened, it will close, if the user is closed it will open.

EDIT:
Below is the explanation of the code `setIsNameShown(prevState => !prevState)`

setIsNameShown or any function that is returned by the useState hook can be written in the below ways.

1st way example:

```
setIsNameShown(false)
```

in this, you are directly passing the value to be set irrespective of the previous value.

2nd way example:

```
setIsNameShown((prevStateVariable) => {
    return !prevStateVariable
})
```

or more concisely this same can be written as

`setIsNameShown(prevStateVariable => !prevStateVariable)`

in this case, the function setIsNameShown accepts the callback function which receives the previous state (to which the function is related to) as an argument.
So in cases where you need to set values to state which depends on the previous state value, use the callback function instead of directly providing the value.

Comment: hey I didn't understand this line ` setIsNameShown(prevState => !prevState)`, can you explain in detail

Comment: ok let me explain it, the function setIsNameShown can either take direct values or a call back function, using a call back function is always preferred if your value depends on the previous value. I will edit my code above and give an example

Comment: hey, I read the first time, still, I didn't understand. Again I am going to read it again. In my interview they asked me one more question, suppose there are millions of users what's the effective way of adding click events

Comment: hey, we are not using prevStateVariable  other than that line, still confused. can you explain with an example

Comment: Hey @computer cool, that variable prevStateVariable can be named anything, that’s an argument automatically passed as the first argument to that callback which will have the previous state.

Comment: @computer cool, also, if you got the solution for your initial problem, pls mark the answer as accepted and give an upvote, this can help us and others in this community. Thanks

Comment: @computer cool, to make you more clear about it, please read this article https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/  especially the section "Example: Updating state based on previous state (useState with a number)"

Comment: @Tick20 I don't think Computer Cool understands how SO works. It looks like he is preparing for an interview and wants us to teach him React. I have pivoted your answer to at least reward you for some of the time wasted. I'd appreciate if you could upvote mine too as you used my answer in yours.

Comment: @JMadelaine, I guess the same :)

Comment: @Tick20 I have upvoted your answer so we can at least get some points for the effort we've put in. I'd appreciate it if you could return the favor :)

Comment: @Tick20 thanks. I just misspelled upvote and couldn't edit my comment! Lol

Comment: @JMadelaine, no problem!

Comment: sorry guys I accepted the answer, I didn't know how to accept, I am not able to increase the answers since I don't have reputations

Comment: @computer cool, it’s okay, no problem. Always happy to help. But when you have new questions, please post it as next question, in that way it can give attention to more developers and you will get good solutions.

Comment: can you please remove negative marks, since I tried and posted :(

Comment: @computer cool, I did not put the negative mark for you :), but it can be anyone else in this community, but I can give you an upvote so that one negative vote will disappear.

Comment: @Tick20 hey suppose if we didn't get the data through js object, and if we have the data in the div like I mentioned in my question, is it still possible to hide and show. Since that was my actual question

Comment: @computer cool, the data is still displayed inside the div in this solution, only difference is we iterate over the data and display it in the div where as in your question you are  hard coding your data inside separate divs which isn’t practical. You will always receive the data in some format, mostly JSON and you convert it into js object and use it like in the solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Tick20 hey I tested your code in sandbox, only when I click on user 1 and user 2 name should hide, but right now when I click on name also its hiding :( https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-blackwell-951th

Comment: @computer cool, ok so now I want you to start thinking, if you understood the code until now, it is very easy to get a solution to that, right now we have added the click listener on the parent div, which makes it possible to click anywhere inside to trigger the hide/show function. So change the click listener and see.

Answer (score 1):

The `useState` hook is just like a class component's `state` and `setState`. In your case `show` is the state variable that has a `true` or `false` value, and you can change this value using the function `setShow`.

To conditionally show the users' names, you should use the value of `show` like so:

```
return(
  <div>
    <div onClick={() => setShow(true)}>user1</div>
    {show && <div>John</div>}
    <div onClick={() => setShow(true)}>user2</div>
    {show && <div>Mike</div>}
  </div>
)
```

However, I don't think that is what you want. It sounds like you want to show only the name of the user that was clicked, and in the current state, when you click one user, all usernames will show because they all depend on the same state variable `show`.

You should create a separate component that contains the logic to show and hide a username, and map each user to that component. That way, each user has their own `show` state.

---

EDIT:

I've updated your code with the below:

```
// each user gets mapped to this component
const UserItem = ({user}) => {
  // that means each user has their own 'isNameShown' variable
  const [isNameShown, setIsNameShown] = useState(false)

  return (
    // if you click this div, this user's isNameShown value will be set to true
    <div onClick={() => setIsNameShown(true)}>
      // user.id is the id of the user from props
      <div>{user.id}</div>
      // only show this user's name if this user's isNameShown is true
      {isNameShown && <div>{user.name}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}

function DataClick(){

  // we just create some example users here for testing
  const users = [
    {
      id: 'user1',
      name: 'John',
    },
    {
      id: 'user2',
      name: 'Peter',
    },
  ]

  return(
    <div>
      // map each user to a UserItem, passing the user as a prop
      {users.map(user => <UserItem user={user} />)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I don't know what your `users` data structure looks like, so you should change it accordingly.

Something to learn here is that, if you find yourself repeating code over and over or copy pasting things again and again, then there is usually a better way of achieving what you want. Your list of users was basically copied and pasted over and over again, so you should create a single `UserItem` component instead.

There may be on issue with this code, which is that once a username is visible, you cannot hide it again, but I'll let you figure out how to do that if that is your intention.

Comment: hey when I click one user that user name alone should so, can you update my stackblitz so confusing :(

Comment: hey do I need to update anything in the showItem function

Comment: I've updated my answer. Do you understand what is going on here and why I have created a separate `UserItem` component?

Comment: hey I need to hide it back too :( you give code comments its hard to understand :(

Comment: I've commented my code, which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: hey why are you passing u here and why as an object --->  `user={u}`

Comment: `users.map(u => <UserItem user={u} />)`. The value `u` is an object that contains the properties `id` and `name`. It is a single item from the array `users`. I'm passing it to the UserItem as a prop called `user` so I can access `u`'s properties inside the `UserItem` component as `user.id` and `user.name`. I have renamed `u` to `user` in the example so it is clear to see that I'm mapping a user to the `UserItem` component.

Comment: As far as, why as an object, what is the alternative? A string? But a user is not a string. If you mean why do I use curly braces when I say `user={u}`, that's the way you pass values as props to a component. If I wrote `user="u"`, then I would literally pass the string "u" to the component, which is not what I want.

Comment: here is `UserItem` child or Parent component, how to find is it child or parent, since in most interviews they ask me how to pass values from child to parent and between same siblings

Comment: It is a child component.

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: hey how to hide the user details if another user is clicked

Comment: That was not part of your original question. If you're having trouble hiding usernames when another is clicked then ask a new question and show what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, we're here to help you fix problems that you've tried to fix yourself. If my answer helped you then please mark it as the accepted answer and I'd be happy to help you with your next problem.

Comment: hey how are you telling UserItem  is a child component?

Comment: Because UserItem is rendered inside DataClick, therefore it is a child of DataClick. There is no difference between a parent and child component. "Child component" is a term to describe a component that is rendered inside another component.